# Keras model not learning if ReLU is the output activation

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using keras to train a regressional NN.

There is a problem. I would like to have my output non-negative. My training data is non-negative in range(0,1).

When I try to use sigmoid or relu in last output layer, the model is not learning anymore.

```
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr1)

modelx = tf.keras.Sequential()
modelx.add(keras.Input(shape=(3,)))
modelx.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
modelx.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
modelx.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='relu' ))

modelx.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="mse", metrics=['mse','mae'])
history = modelx.fit(X, Y, epochs=epp[i],batch_size=bs1,shuffle=True)
```

I keep getting constant loss function.

```
   Epoch 1/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 832us/step - loss: 0.0617 - mse: 0.0617 - mae: 0.1283
Epoch 2/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 753us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 3/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 657us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 4/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 709us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 5/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 668us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 6/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 552us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 7/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 702us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 8/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 595us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 9/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 633us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 10/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 855us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 11/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 681us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 12/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 620us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 13/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 572us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 14/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 618us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
Epoch 15/15
8/8 [==============================] - 0s 572us/step - loss: 0.0197 - mse: 0.0197 - mae: 0.0731
```

If I am using something that can be negative (ELU, leaky relu), it converges once again, but I don't like the results (a lot of negative predictions)

This is the data used in traning:

```
Y is
[1.33931561e-04 6.18145666e-05 3.52451476e-05 2.14290498e-05
 1.29611188e-05 7.23954384e-06 3.11468746e-06 0.00000000e+00
 2.34380232e-03 1.25174497e-03 8.49408058e-04 6.40192861e-04
 5.11964193e-04 4.25323200e-04 3.62861090e-04 3.15695822e-04
 4.55367307e-03 2.44167538e-03 1.66357097e-03 1.25895667e-03
 1.01096727e-03 8.43406857e-04 7.22607492e-04 6.31391645e-04
 6.76354383e-03 3.63160579e-03 2.47773388e-03 1.87772048e-03
 1.50997034e-03 1.26149051e-03 1.08235389e-03 9.47087467e-04
 8.97341459e-03 4.82153620e-03 3.29189679e-03 2.49648430e-03
 2.00897341e-03 1.67957417e-03 1.44210030e-03 1.26278329e-03
 1.11832853e-02 6.01146660e-03 4.10605970e-03 3.11524811e-03
 2.50797649e-03 2.09765783e-03 1.80184670e-03 1.57847911e-03
 1.33931561e-02 7.20139701e-03 4.92022261e-03 3.73401192e-03
 3.00697956e-03 2.51574148e-03 2.16159310e-03 1.89417493e-03
 1.56030269e-02 8.39132742e-03 5.73438552e-03 4.35277573e-03
 3.50598264e-03 2.93382514e-03 2.52133950e-03 2.20987076e-03
 6.02692024e-04 3.14224047e-04 2.07946371e-04 1.52681980e-04
 1.18810256e-04 9.59239558e-05 7.94245303e-05 6.69657805e-05
 9.44217505e-03 5.07394568e-03 3.46459801e-03 2.62773723e-03
 2.11482255e-03 1.76825858e-03 1.51841014e-03 1.32974907e-03
 1.82816581e-02 9.83366730e-03 6.72124965e-03 5.10279247e-03
 4.11083485e-03 3.44059321e-03 2.95739575e-03 2.59253236e-03
 2.71211411e-02 1.45933889e-02 9.97790129e-03 7.57784772e-03
 6.10684714e-03 5.11292783e-03 4.39638136e-03 3.85531565e-03
 3.59606241e-02 1.93531106e-02 1.32345529e-02 1.00529030e-02
 8.10285944e-03 6.78526246e-03 5.83536696e-03 5.11809894e-03
 4.48001071e-02 2.41128322e-02 1.64912046e-02 1.25279582e-02
 1.00988717e-02 8.45759709e-03 7.27435257e-03 6.38088223e-03
 5.36395902e-02 2.88725538e-02 1.97478562e-02 1.50030135e-02
 1.20948840e-02 1.01299317e-02 8.71333818e-03 7.64366552e-03
 6.24790732e-02 3.36322754e-02 2.30045079e-02 1.74780687e-02
 1.40908963e-02 1.18022663e-02 1.01523238e-02 8.90644880e-03
 1.38395946e-03 7.34906514e-04 4.95781743e-04 3.71436862e-04
 2.95225484e-04 2.43731309e-04 2.06607602e-04 1.78575415e-04
 2.12727963e-02 1.14442802e-02 7.82324793e-03 5.94031117e-03
 4.78625315e-03 4.00648422e-03 3.44432522e-03 3.01983782e-03
 4.11616331e-02 2.21536538e-02 1.51507141e-02 1.15091855e-02
 9.27728081e-03 7.76923713e-03 6.68204284e-03 5.86110022e-03
 6.10504699e-02 3.28630275e-02 2.24781803e-02 1.70780598e-02
 1.37683085e-02 1.15319900e-02 9.91976046e-03 8.70236262e-03
 8.09393067e-02 4.35724012e-02 2.98056465e-02 2.26469341e-02
 1.82593361e-02 1.52947429e-02 1.31574781e-02 1.15436250e-02
 1.00828143e-01 5.42817748e-02 3.71331127e-02 2.82158084e-02
 2.27503638e-02 1.90574959e-02 1.63951957e-02 1.43848874e-02
 1.20716980e-01 6.49911485e-02 4.44605789e-02 3.37846827e-02
 2.72413915e-02 2.28202488e-02 1.96329133e-02 1.72261498e-02
 1.40605817e-01 7.57005222e-02 5.17880451e-02 3.93535570e-02
 3.17324191e-02 2.65830017e-02 2.28706309e-02 2.00674122e-02
 2.47773388e-03 1.32386197e-03 8.98751264e-04 6.77693699e-04
 5.42206803e-04 4.50661604e-04 3.84663902e-04 3.34828902e-04
 3.78356660e-02 2.03627485e-02 1.39253578e-02 1.05779147e-02
 8.52625599e-03 7.14000011e-03 6.14060634e-03 5.38596206e-03
 7.31935981e-02 3.94016350e-02 2.69519644e-02 2.04781357e-02
 1.65103052e-02 1.38293386e-02 1.18965488e-02 1.04370952e-02
 1.08551530e-01 5.84405215e-02 3.99785710e-02 3.03783567e-02
 2.44943544e-02 2.05186771e-02 1.76524912e-02 1.54882284e-02
 1.43909462e-01 7.74794080e-02 5.30051775e-02 4.02785776e-02
 3.24784035e-02 2.72080156e-02 2.34084336e-02 2.05393615e-02
 1.79267394e-01 9.65182945e-02 6.60317841e-02 5.01787986e-02
 4.04624527e-02 3.38973541e-02 2.91643761e-02 2.55904947e-02
 2.14625326e-01 1.15557181e-01 7.90583906e-02 6.00790196e-02
 4.84465019e-02 4.05866926e-02 3.49203185e-02 3.06416278e-02
 2.49983259e-01 1.34596068e-01 9.20849972e-02 6.99792406e-02
 5.64305511e-02 4.72760311e-02 4.06762609e-02 3.56927610e-02
 3.88401527e-03 2.08109041e-03 1.41685493e-03 1.07145249e-03
 8.59754214e-04 7.16714840e-04 6.13593431e-04 5.35726244e-04
 5.91307842e-02 3.18293506e-02 2.17709277e-02 1.65405478e-02
 1.33348311e-02 1.11688063e-02 9.60725348e-03 8.42812180e-03
 1.14377553e-01 6.15776108e-02 4.21250004e-02 3.20096431e-02
 2.58099079e-02 2.16208977e-02 1.86009135e-02 1.63205174e-02
 1.69624322e-01 9.13258709e-02 6.24790732e-02 4.74787384e-02
 3.82849848e-02 3.20729891e-02 2.75945736e-02 2.42129129e-02
 2.24871091e-01 1.21074131e-01 8.28331459e-02 6.29478337e-02
 5.07600616e-02 4.25250805e-02 3.65882336e-02 3.21053085e-02
 2.80117860e-01 1.50822391e-01 1.03187219e-01 7.84169289e-02
 6.32351385e-02 5.29771719e-02 4.55818937e-02 3.99977040e-02
 3.35364629e-01 1.80570651e-01 1.23541291e-01 9.38860242e-02
 7.57102153e-02 6.34292633e-02 5.45755538e-02 4.78900996e-02
 3.90611398e-01 2.10318912e-01 1.43895364e-01 1.09355120e-01
 8.81852922e-02 7.38813547e-02 6.35692138e-02 5.57824951e-02
 5.60280363e-03 3.00659184e-03 2.05009275e-03 1.55271323e-03
 1.24786772e-03 1.04189102e-03 8.93396188e-04 7.81267439e-04
 8.51581509e-02 4.58440865e-02 3.13599575e-02 2.38282105e-02
 1.92119784e-02 1.60929027e-02 1.38442667e-02 1.21463170e-02
 1.64713498e-01 8.86815811e-02 6.06698223e-02 4.61037077e-02
 3.71760890e-02 3.11439143e-02 2.67951371e-02 2.35113666e-02
 2.44268845e-01 1.31519076e-01 8.99796870e-02 6.83792049e-02
 5.51401997e-02 4.61949259e-02 3.97460076e-02 3.48764162e-02
 3.23824193e-01 1.74356570e-01 1.19289552e-01 9.06547021e-02
 7.31043104e-02 6.12459376e-02 5.26968781e-02 4.62414658e-02
 4.03379540e-01 2.17194065e-01 1.48599417e-01 1.12930199e-01
 9.10684210e-02 7.62969492e-02 6.56477486e-02 5.76065155e-02
 4.82934887e-01 2.60031560e-01 1.77909281e-01 1.35205697e-01
 1.09032532e-01 9.13479608e-02 7.85986191e-02 6.89715651e-02
 5.62490234e-01 3.02869054e-01 2.07219146e-01 1.57481194e-01
 1.26996642e-01 1.06398972e-01 9.15494895e-02 8.03366147e-02
 7.63409898e-03 4.10036625e-03 2.79846472e-03 2.12147593e-03
 1.70654731e-03 1.42619014e-03 1.22407217e-03 1.07145249e-03
 1.15917766e-01 6.24069562e-02 4.26924473e-02 3.24409027e-02
 2.61576979e-02 2.19122893e-02 1.88516459e-02 1.65405478e-02
 2.24201433e-01 1.20713546e-01 8.25864299e-02 6.27603295e-02
 5.06088486e-02 4.23983885e-02 3.64792196e-02 3.20096431e-02
 3.32485100e-01 1.79020136e-01 1.22480413e-01 9.30797562e-02
 7.50599992e-02 6.28844876e-02 5.41067933e-02 4.74787384e-02
 4.40768767e-01 2.37326726e-01 1.62374395e-01 1.23399183e-01
 9.95111498e-02 8.33705868e-02 7.17343670e-02 6.29478337e-02
 5.49052434e-01 2.95633316e-01 2.02268378e-01 1.53718610e-01
 1.23962300e-01 1.03856686e-01 8.93619407e-02 7.84169289e-02
 6.57336101e-01 3.53939906e-01 2.42162360e-01 1.84038037e-01
 1.48413451e-01 1.24342785e-01 1.06989514e-01 9.38860242e-02
 7.65619768e-01 4.12246496e-01 2.82056343e-01 2.14357463e-01
 1.72864602e-01 1.44828884e-01 1.24617088e-01 1.09355120e-01
 9.97790129e-03 5.36241365e-03 3.66197084e-03 2.77774057e-03
 2.23579299e-03 1.86961220e-03 1.60562139e-03 1.40628139e-03
 1.51409630e-01 8.15179597e-02 5.57683971e-02 4.23786245e-02
 3.41719897e-02 2.86269662e-02 2.46293911e-02 2.16108140e-02
 2.92841358e-01 1.57673506e-01 1.07874823e-01 8.19795085e-02
 6.61081865e-02 5.53843202e-02 4.76531609e-02 4.18153466e-02
 4.34273086e-01 2.33829052e-01 1.59981250e-01 1.21580392e-01
 9.80443832e-02 8.21416743e-02 7.06769306e-02 6.20198793e-02
 5.75704815e-01 3.09984598e-01 2.12087676e-01 1.61181276e-01
 1.29980580e-01 1.08899028e-01 9.37007003e-02 8.22244119e-02
 7.17136543e-01 3.86140144e-01 2.64194102e-01 2.00782160e-01
 1.61916777e-01 1.35656382e-01 1.16724470e-01 1.02428945e-01
 8.58568272e-01 4.62295690e-01 3.16300528e-01 2.40383044e-01
 1.93852973e-01 1.62413736e-01 1.39748240e-01 1.22633477e-01
 1.00000000e+00 5.38451236e-01 3.68406955e-01 2.79983928e-01
 2.25789170e-01 1.89171090e-01 1.62772010e-01 1.42838010e-01]
X is
[[0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.14285714]
 [0.         0.         0.28571429]
 ...
 [1.         1.         0.71428571]
 [1.         1.         0.85714286]
 [1.         1.         1.        ]]
```

As you can see, it is non-negative.

Please tell me how could I change it to give only positive predictions.

Comment: For regression models, you must not use an activation function in the last layer!

Comment: @MojtabaAbdiKh. No, that is not true, for continuous labels in [0, 1] sigmoid is a good choice for regression.

Comment: As we see here, there are no labels here. They are just continuous values. The other point to adding is that, I have read a batch of books. I've never heard about something like continuous labels. @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: Continuous labels and output is just regression

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a regression problem. In your last layer still you are using `relu` activation function. For regression models, you shouldn't use `activation` in the last layer. I will recommend to remove `relu` from the last layer and retrain the model.